# React’s new context api with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have been using enzyme and love it a lot. It works with react 16 until I wanted to test my new project that uses react’s new context api.

If I render only my basic component using shallow and console log the debug of the component I can see its content but when I use the new context api with provider and consumer, I get `<undefined />` as a render out. Enzyme does not render the component but react does.

Can someone please provide some guidance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Support for this and other React 16.3 features are going to be included in the next enzyme release which is going to happen in midst summer, this year (as said [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/1513#issuecomment-388173895)).

For now, here's a workaround:

```
const outer = shallow(<SimpleComp />);
const Children = outer.props().children({ /* context */ });
const wrapper = shallow(Children);
```

*To use mount() with new Context API use [this enzyme patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-context-patch).*

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: When I try this method I receive an error saying: "children is not a function". Is this featuring a specific version of enzyme?

Comment: I think that Enzyme has released already the fix, but not sure how to use it. Anyone know?

Comment: I would say that this is more correct: ```const outer = shallow(<SimpleComp />);
const wrapper = outer.props().children({ /* context */ });```

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Where did you see that they released it? Couldn't find it in the changelog.

Comment: I am not sure I can find the URL again :/

Comment: I don't think support to new style Context API is available in enzyme yet. See https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/14329