# Shallow render a component which is a class that uses context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a component using `shallow` with enzyme. The component I am trying to test is a class and doing context like so:

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;
  ...
```

and using it in that component `const { url } = this.context;`

When writing the test this has been used:

```
const contextWrapper = {
  wrappingComponent: AppContext,
  wrappingComponentProps: { url: 'http://appUrl.com' },
};
```

and here is the snapshot test as an example which is using mount as this seems to be the only way to get context to work.

```
it('should render correctly', () => {
  const output = mount(<Comonent {...props} />, contextWrapper);
  expect(shallowToJson(output)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I have done some refactoring and in this file there is a component which is connected to the store. When using mount it expects a store to be provided to that component which is why I would like to us `shallow`.

If I wrap `Component` with a `<Provider store={store}>` I can get this to all work but I have a test further down trying to access state on `Component` but it is blank and can't find it.

Here is a snippet of the test where state is not found:

```
const output = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    < ExampleComponent {...newProps} />
  </Provider>,
  contextWrapper,
);
expect(output.state('stateValue')).toBe(true);
```

and this is the error shown:

```
ReactWrapper::state("stateValue") requires that `state` not be `null` or `undefined`
```

Is there a way to use `shallow` and context? I have found this package to 'fix' it for now [shallow-with-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-with-context) but I am not sure if that is correct? I have also seen old posts saying enzyme doesn't support the new context api. is that correct? What is the best method to solve this issue?

Comment: I know it's not really an answer to your question, but why you don't want to use `mount` - given all the problems that I've had using it I don't recommend it to anyone, especially if you need to use legacy context API, because `shallow` doesn't suport new... As for your question - maybe this answer would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737711/react-s-new-context-api-with-enzyme. Also, you can check progress on updating enzyme here: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1553#issue-301920052

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. when i use mount I have to provide a store as a child component is connected to the store. if i do that then one of the tests trying to access state on the ExampleComponent cant be found. Am i not doing it right? That answer might help. i can give it a go. thanks!